# Transparent backgrounds are black with GTK+

Tags: themes, gtk

GTK+ was giving me a few issues with large black borders around some windows, I created a CSS file to modify this to remove the box shadow around the window and the border.

There is still a tiny but annoying black around the window where there is a border radius and I have been trying to eliminate that.

[image: Image showing a black border around the edge of the window]

After debugging for a little while I figured out its due to the fact that it cannot display transparency correctly and just displays black instead.

Here is an example:

[image: Image showing window completely black even though css is set to transparent]

Is there any way of doing this with the gtk's implementation css alone?

Comment: You will have better chance for answer, if you include the code you have modified to get that behavio.

Comment: Make sure you are running new DEs like XFCE or GNOME. If you are running them already, make sure you ran the compositor.